# Pass data to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Trying to create a asp.net mvc app in c# to import a excel file into a database.
I am able to open the file and can get the column headers out by using

> Columns.HeaderText

however how do I get the ROW values into a list to pass to my controller.

I know I need to do something like Send the list to the controller, loop through the list array and then insert into database.

```
int columnTotal = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
string[] columnNames = new string[150];
for (int columnCount = 0; columnCount < columnTotal; columnCount++)
{
    columnNames[columnCount] = dataGridView1.Columns[columnCount].HeaderText;
}

    List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

    int rowTotal = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    string[] columnValues = new string[150];

    string rowValue = ""; 
    //int currentRow = 0;

    for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < rowTotal; rowCount++)
           {
            //Need to implement
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
//list = list.add(row);
            }

            Controller cn = new Controller();

    //ToDo: this goes to controller and passes through column names and the list  
    cn.UpdateDatabase(columnNames, list);
```

Comment: What is the `Controller cn = new Controller();` in your code? I don't get it what you want to do... You want some specific action in controller that imports excel file to the database, right?

Comment: The controller is yet to be implemented, I was putting that code in there as I think thats what i need to pass through to the controller, the column names and the list array.

Comment: Wondering how do I get the list of row values associated to the column headers so i can pass the list array variable through to the controller.

Comment: I think you lack knowledge about how MVC works... I suggest you read a good tutorial first http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

Comment: Although I agree I lack knowledge on mvc but I do realise  the theory it uses.

Basically I have a method that I am working on, this then gets passed to the controller.

I am trying to pass the data in my datagridview into my controller.
I am certain you can create a list, populate this list with the data in the rows of the datagrid and then pass this list to the controller, and then in the controller you have a method to loop through the list and insert this data into a sql database.

Comment: You don't pass the method to the controller. The controller can invoke a method instead. You need some data access layer for obtaining your data from datagrid and another one for read/write operations in your database. Then you would create a service for all of that but well... I suggest you try and read some more tutorials before trying to write some more complicated examples.